# How to reference Mongoose data model from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, passport.js

How do you reference a Mongoose model in another file in a MEAN application? I am in `login.js` and need to reference `user.js` to `findOrCreate` a user. Are my paths wrong or did I initialize the model incorrectly? My error is **undefined is not a function** on the line to create a user.

File structure

```
root
    models
        user.js
    passport
        login.js
    ...
        ...
```

**login.js**

```
var User = require('./../models/user');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

module.exports = function(passport){

    // Google login
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({ 
        clientID: 'id',
        clientSecret: 'secret',
        callbackURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback'
    }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

        // Problem here? 
        User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
            return done(err, user);
        });
    }));
};
```

**user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', {

    googleId: {type: String, unique: true, required: true}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your user.js file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = mongoose.model(
    'User', 
    new Schema({
         googleId: {type: String, unique: true, required: true}
    }
));
```

You might know more about [Schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) class.